# If I combine UA and AW in the same gtag.js, will my analytic and marketing cookies be triggered at the same time?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, gtag.js

I have UA and AW integrated into the same gtag.js. I wonder if analytical cookies (AU) are applied together with marketing cookies (AW) and vice versa, because the IDs are in the same code snippet? Because I want that there is no connection between them, even if they are included in the same snippet. So that means if my user confirms marketing cookies, the analytic cookies will not be triggered and vice versa. Thank you.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX');
    gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXX');
</script>
<script>
    gtag('event', 'page_view', {
        'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXX',
        'dynx_itemid': 'replace with value'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know that UA is universal analytics, but I've never heard of AW.  What is that for?

Comment: Google Ads :) @StephenOstermiller